# Submersions are open maps

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I am trying to prove that a submersion is an open map.

There is a hint that locally there are coordinates in which the submersion can be shown as the projection onto the first few coordinates and I know that projections are open maps, but I don't know how to show that the submersion is a projection.

Thanks!

Comment: The representation as projection uses so called Rank Theorem in Lee's smooth manifold.

Answer (score 2):

If $F:N\rightarrow M$ is  a submersion then as you mentioned, it is locally a projection map.
Suppose $O$ is open in $M$. Let $F(p)\in F(O)$ for some $p\in O$. Since $F$ is locally a projection map and projection maps are open maps, there exists an open subset $W$ of $N$ such that $F(p)\in W\subseteq F(O)$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:X^{n+k}\to Y^n$ is a submersion and $U\subset X$ is open. If $x\in U$, then there exist diffeomorphisms $\phi:\Bbb R^{n+k}\to X$ and $\psi:\Bbb R^n\to Y$ parametrizing $x$ and $f(x)$, respectively, such that
$$
f = \psi\circ \pi\circ\phi^{-1}.
$$
Where $\pi:\Bbb R^{n+k}\to\Bbb R^{n}$ is the canonical projection. If we take $\tilde U\subset U$ sufficiently small and open, then since diffeomorphisms are open, and the projection is open, then
$f(\tilde U) \subset f(U)$ is a neighborhood of $f(x)$, so that $f$ is an open map.